How to allow shortcodes in image descriptions?
I understand how to add a filter to enable shortcodes for something:
add_filter( 'img_description', 'do_shortcode' );
But, what's the actual hook to target image descriptions? img_description doesn't exist and is just a placeholder.

where do you want render shortcode in description ? in front office pages ?

@mmm Yes, I already display the image description below images on the front-end, which accepts HTML. Now, I'm just trying to allow shortcodes too.

Could you please try to use the wp_get_attachment_caption hook, this will helps you in enabling shortcode for Image caption field.
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_caption', 'do_shortcode' );

